# how to call function from other function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I have some functions like php class

```
    var myclass = function(){
    function func1(){
        //ragaca
    }
    function func2(){

    }
};
```

I need to call func2 function from outside
I googled and find some functions
e.x. .live or .trigger
but no one working

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myclass = function(){
    function func1(){
        console.log('hello');
    }

    function func2(){
        console.log('world');
    }

    return {
        func1:func1,
        func2: func2
    };
};

var My = new myclass();
My.func2();
```

Comment: @insanehong Code-only answers are discouraged. Please consider providing some commentary.

Comment: @aliteralmind ok, got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and avoid creating new instances:

```
var myCls = {
    fnOne: function() {
        console.log('fnOne fired');
    },
    fnTwo: function() {
        console.log('fnTwo fired');
    }
};

myCls.fnOne();
myCls.fnTwo();
```